# Отобразить при наведении скрытый текст

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, clipboard.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, имеется код. По нажатию на кнопку копируется текст, как сделать, чтобы при наведении на кнопку показывался скрытый текст из data-clipboard-text. Код прилагаю:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">    
 <title>Речевки</title>
 
 <style type="text/css">
 html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:700}dfn{font-style:italic}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-.5em}sub{bottom:-.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}pre{overflow:auto}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}input{line-height:normal}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto}optgroup{font-weight:700}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0}
 body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  text-align: left;
 }
 </style>
    <script src="http://www.net-f.ru/primer/clipboard/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.net-f.ru/jss/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="font-size: 14px; position: relative; padding: 0;">
 <table class="table">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТ">НАЖАТЬ</td>
   
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<p>Поле для вставки и редактирования текста</p>
 <textarea rows="20" cols="65" name="text"></textarea>

<style type="text/css">
.table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.table th, .table td {
 border: 1px solid #888;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hover */
.table td:hover:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px; 
 bottom: 0px;    
 left: 0px;
 border: 3px solid #ffe5c5;
}

/* Click */
.table td.active:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px; 
 bottom: 0px;    
 left: 0px;
 border: 3px solid orange !important;
}

</style>

<script src="https://snipp.ru/cdn/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.table th, .table td').click(function(){
  $('.table td').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
</script>
<script>
var cb = new Clipboard('.btn'); // класс кнопки
cb.on('success', function(e){
        // уведомление, можно настроить своё

        // выделение скопированного текста на 1,5 секунды
 window.setTimeout(function(){e.clearSelection();}, 1500);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Как один из вариантов
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button class="but" data-clipboard-text="Не нажимай!">Нажми</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('but')[0];
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");

elem.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
demo.innerHTML = elem.getAttribute("data-clipboard-text");
});

elem.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
demo.innerHTML = "";
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Второй вариант

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
.but {
    width: 90%;
}
.but:before {
    content: 'Нажми!';
    width: 90%;
}
.but:hover::before {
    content: attr(data-clipboard-text);
    color: red;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="but" data-clipboard-text="Не нажимай!"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое отличный вариант, выручили!

Comment: Рад, что помог. Пригодился первый вариант или второй?

Comment: Больше пригодился первый под мои задачи)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.table th, .table td').click(function(){
   $('.table td').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $(".btn").on('mouseover', function() {
   $(this).children(".info").text($(this).attr("data-clipboard-text"));
  });

  $(".btn").on('mouseout', function() {
   $(this).children(".info").text("");
  });
 });
  
  var cb = new Clipboard('.btn'); // класс кнопки
 cb.on('success', function(e){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(true);
   e.clearSelection();
  }, 1500);
 });
```

```css
html{
  font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:700}dfn{font-style:italic}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-.5em}sub{bottom:-.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}pre{overflow:auto}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}input{line-height:normal}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto}optgroup{font-weight:700}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0}
 body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  text-align: left;
 }

 .btn { position: relative; }

 .info { position: absolute; left: 45%; top: 40px; }
  
  .table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%;
 }
 .table th, .table td {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 /* Hover */
 .table td:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px;    
  left: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #ffe5c5;
 }

 /* Click */
 .table td.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px;    
  left: 0px;
  border: 3px solid orange !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.net-f.ru/primer/clipboard/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="ТЕКСТТЕКСТТЕКСТ">НАЖАТЬ <div class="info"></div></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<p>Поле для вставки и редактирования текста</p>
 <textarea rows="20" cols="65" name="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это то что было нужно!